# How many ways can a committee be made? (Counting Rules)

Tags: statistics

A school dance committee is to consist of 2 freshman, 3 sophomores, 4 juniors and 5 seniors. If 7 freshmen, 8 sophomores, 7 juniors, 7 seniors are eligible to be on the committee, in how many ways can the committee be chosen?

Committee Total: 
2 freshmen 
3 sophomores
4 juniors 5 seniors 
Total: 14 committee members

Eligible members: 
7 Freshmen
8 Sophomores
7 Juniors
7 Seniors
Total: 29 eligible members

To find the total outcomes: 
 29C14= 77558760

(2C7)*(3C8)*(4C7)*(5C7)/77558760= 0

Does that mean that there is 0 possible ways? 
I am not sure if I did this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's talk about the resources available to you:

1. 7 Freshmen are Eligible, you need 2.
2. 8 Sophomores are Eligible, you need 3.
3. 7 Juniors are Eligible, you need 4.
4. 7 Seniors are Eligible, you need 5.

In other words, you need to choose a certain number of people from each group of students. That can be done using the binomial coefficients:

Number of ways of choosing Freshmen: ${7 \choose 2}$ = 21

Number of ways of choosing Sophomores: ${8 \choose 3}$ = 56

Number of ways of choosing Juniors: ${7 \choose 4}$ = 35

Number of ways of choosing Seniors: ${7 \choose 5}$ = 21

Given that you have 4 events and you're counting the total number of ways to do these 4 events as a whole, you just need to multiply each of the numbers above and you will get:

Total Number of ways of choosing the committee: 56.35.21.21 = 864360

The reason why you're wrong is because you did the 'choosing' in the wrong way. You can't choose 7 objects from 2 objects. That doesn't make any sense. Furthermore, what you actually calculated would've been the probability of choosing the combination that the question asked for IF the individual doing the choosing had to pick completely at random.

**Just a note here:**

${n \choose k}$ represents the number of ways in which you can choose *k* objects from *n* objects. To derive the explicit formula for doing it, consider *n* identical objects that have been placed in front of you.

Suppose you want to pick out *k* of them. For the first choice, you have *n* options. For the second choice, you have (n-1) options. For the third choice, you have (n-3) options. So, for all *k* objects, you have:

n(n-1)(n-2).........(n-k+1)

Now, obviously, if you have *k* objects, there are exactly k! ways of arranging these objects in a line. However, if these are identical, then you can't distinguish one arrangement from the other. To put it simply, the string 'AA' is indistinguishable from the string 'AA'. However, the counting above took all of these possibilities into account and so, you need to divide the number above with k! in order to get the formula you want:

${n \choose k}$ = $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2).....(n-k+1)}{k!}$